# What is the reason of this Internet Connection Failure on Linux and VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, internet

I installed Ubuntu linux distribution 10.04 on VirtualBox 4.2.12. The host os is windows 7. Now I want to do connect use wget. But the result is like:

```
wget www.google.com
Resolving www.google.com... 173.194.127.84, 173.194.127.80, 173.194.127.81, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|173.194.127.84|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
...
Connecting to www.google.com|173.194.127.83|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.google.com|2404:6800:4005:801::1011|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

But I can browse 173.194.127.84 using Firefox on linux. I just cannot figure that why I cannot use wget to connect to the Internet but can connect with Firefox? It is very strange. I want to know the reason why this thing happen.

BTW my host uses fixed IP to access to the Internet. I only have one IP to access to the Internet, so I'm using the NAT mode in VirtualBox.

Comment: Do not you use a web proxy in the network? Do you see anything else than "No proxy" if you in Firefox open **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **Network** > **Connection** > **Settings**? What do you have there? Please check also the [system proxy setting](http://askubuntu.com/a/15721/67132) and the environment variable `http_proxy` (Run in command line: `export http_proxy`).

Comment: in Firefox Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Network > Connection > Settings, my setting is set as "Use system proxy setting". The command export http_proxy returns nothing.

Comment: Without `http_proxy` variable or appropriate command line option `wget` will not use a proxy. If you are not sure about requirement of a proxy setting in your network, please try to set Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Network > Connection > Settings in Firefox to "No proxy" and test if the same URLs which fail in `wget` can be accessed in Firefox.

Comment: In System > Preference > Network Proxy > Automatic Proxy Configuration I set to use a .pac file (e.g. http://myserver.com/proxy.pac ).Actually I have set Use system proxy setting in Firefox Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Network > Connection > Settings. I think I should set the http_proxy variable the .pac file. I've placed http_proxy=http://myserver.com/proxy.pac export http_proxy in .bashrc, but it didn't work.

Comment: OK, so it seems that the proxy is required in your network.   Unfortunately you cannot use `.pac` files with `http_proxy` variable. They are too complicated. Please look into the `proxy.pac` file and try to find the *`proxy_address`* and *`proxy_port`* values. They are usually in this format: `return "PROXY proxy_address:proxy_port";`. Then set the `http_proxy` variable: `export http_proxy=http://proxy_address:proxy_port`. For testing you do not need to put this command into the shell startup scripts, just run it from the same command line from which you will run `wget`.

Comment: My content of the proxy.pac is a little bit complicated. It returns proxy ip and port depends on the ip which I'm going to connect to. So I think I cannot use a single export command. Besides, in System > Preference > Network Proxy > Automatic Proxy Configuration I set to use the .pac file and clicked the Apply System-wide button, but it doesn't work. Is there any other way to apply the pac file?

Comment: Yes, PAC files could be pretty complicated they can return different values even according to the client IP address and time. Unfortunately the simple command line tools are not able to evaluate the PAC files. Such a setting cannot be really system-wide. I can put together a solution as a wrapper script around wget and similar tools with help of some utilities. Would it be what you need? Could you please meanwhile test one of the proxies from your `proxy.pac` in the `http_proxy` variable?